# Moving background lagging, Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, vertical-scrolling

I'm making a runner and I added a function to make my background be able to "move". It's working but not really smooth, my enemies seems to teleport when pygame refresh the background, that is a little difficult to explain.

I've already tried `convert_alpha()` or `convert()`.

Here's a minimal code of my game that should work and let you see what's wrong, and here is the picture I am using for the background: [background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YxGP.png).

```
from pygame import *
import random
import sys
import pygame

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 750
FPS = 60

SPEEDX = 5
SPEEDY = 3

# define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = image.load("background.png").convert_alpha()

x,y = 0, 0
x1, y1 = 0, -HEIGHT

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT

    def update(self):
        self.SPEEDX = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        #Move right
        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.SPEEDX = SPEEDX
        #Move left
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.SPEEDX = - SPEEDX
        #Close the game
        if keystate[pygame.K_LCTRL] and keystate[pygame.K_z]:
            sys.exit()

        #Make the character moving
        self.rect.x += self.SPEEDX

        #Do not cross screen border
        #Left side
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        #Right side
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        #Bottom side
        if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
            self.image.fill(RED)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
            self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)

        def update(self):
            self.rect.x += self.speedx
            self.rect.y += self.speedy
            if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
                self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
                self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
                self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

def Death():
    player.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
    player.rect.y = HEIGHT
    all_sprites.remove(all_enemies)
    all_enemies.empty()
    for i in range(10):
        enemies = Enemy()
        all_sprites.add(enemies)
        all_enemies.add(enemies)

def Scrolling():

    global x,y,x1,y1

    y1 += 5
    y += 5
    screen.blit(background,(x,y))
    screen.blit(background,(x1,y1))
    if y > HEIGHT:
        y = -HEIGHT
    if y1 > HEIGHT:
        y1 = -HEIGHT

player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

for i in range(10):
    enemies = Enemy()
    all_sprites.add(enemies)
    all_enemies.add(enemies)


# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    if sprite.spritecollide(player, all_enemies, True):
        Death()

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()

    # Draw / render
    Scrolling()
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Name functions with `lowercase_underscore` and classes with `CamelCase` to avoid confusion between names of functions and classes. And try to define all attributes in `__init__` so it's easy to identify them. `self.SPEEDX` is for example defined in `update` (which could be a local variable instead of an attribute). Anyway, could you elaborate on what you mean with lagging? I ran the program with no such issue. If it's hard to explain then try to post images, drawings, youtube videos, gifs or something else that helps.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply I will do it this night.

Comment: Do you mean the sprites and the background jitter or jump a little bit? That happens because of Pygame's lack of vsync. Unfortunately, there's no way to fix this, so you have to live wih it.

Comment: Yes it's some little jump. Thanks for the reply. Should be the vsync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably vSync thanks to skrx for the answer and to everyone for the time.